# How to plot an arrow when MACD is exactly at midline?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to plot an arrow when macdline is exactly at the midline, i.e. when macdline is equal to zero.

This is the code I am using:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macdline = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macdline, signal_length) : ta.ema(macdline, signal_length)
hist = macdline - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macdline, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)

//plot arrow when macd is equal to midline
midline = 0
plotshape(macd=midline),style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.orange, size=size.small)
```

I got this error:

> No value assigned to the `series` parameter

Can someone help me and tell me what code I should use?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by a missing parameter in the `plotshape` function because the variable `macd` doesn't exist.
Besides, your code has another problem, the `macdline` is never equal to `0`, as the values that you see on the chart are rounded.

This is the correct code:

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macdline = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macdline, signal_length) : ta.ema(macdline, signal_length)
hist = macdline - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macdline, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)

//plot arrow when macd is equal to midline
plotshape(math.floor(macdline)==0,style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.orange, size=size.small)
```

Comment: Thanks SpaceX. 
I pasted code and the result I got was that an arrow is dispalyed everytime the macdline is above zero and not just when the macdline is equal to zero as requested. Could this be due to the math.floor please?

Comment: This should be pretty accurate, but remember that the macdline is almost never 0.       
'plotshape(macdline < 0.1 and macdline >= 0,style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=color.orange, size=size.small)'

Comment: Thanks once again. Further to your observation that macdline is almost never zero, whenever the macdline crosses the midline isn't that when the macdline is zero?

Comment: I mean that the macdline is never precisely equal to zero.